# GCP Pub/Sub Dataflow template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, bucket

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery template and Pub/Sub Subscription to BigQuery template?
I want to create a bigquery table when I upload file into a bucket using dataflow, pubsub and terraform.
I wanted to use one of GCP's template from my dataflow but I am not sure which template should I use.
Can you help me understand the difference between the two and in which case should I use one and not the other please?

The use case of each dataflow template

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what you should use for the template but I believe understanding the pubsub topic descriptions will help you to choose what to use. Topics and Subcriptions are some of the essential resources for pubsub.

1. **Topic**. A named resource to which messages are sent by publishers.
2. **Subscription**. A named resource representing the stream of messages from a single, specific topic, to be delivered to the subscribing application.

You can check these descriptions/overview [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#core_concepts)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is what happens to the messages published prior to the pipeline start or restart. If you use Pub/Sub Subscription to BigQuery, then all messages published since the **time when the subscription was created** will be written to BigQuery. If you use Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery, then **only data published to the topic after the pipeline is started** will be written to BigQuery. The latter template creates its own subscription and recreates it whenever the pipeline restarts, which is why this happens.

So the choice depends on how much continuity you want out of the data in the event the pipeline restarts. If you want all of the data published prior, use the template where you specify the subscription. If you only want the data published while the job is running, use the template where you specify the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it clears up a lot.
I thought that we should use the Dataflow Pub/Sub Subscription to BigQuery template when we have multiple data sources, and each source needs to be processed in a different way or with different parameters. By creating multiple subscriptions for the same topic but if we only have one job to do and the data source is a single Pub/Sub topic, then using the Dataflow Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery template would be more appropriate.